# There are many different quantile definitions - what diffrentiates and motivates them?

Tags: mathematical-statistics, quantiles, definition

First some standard notation.
A probability triplet is $(\Omega,\mathcal F, P)$. You have a random variable $X : \Omega \to \mathbb{R}$ measurable function. The distribution function is $F(x) = P(X\leq x) = P(\{\omega\in \Omega : X(\omega) \leq x\})$
We know $F$ has left-limits and is right-continous.

Below I give three notions of quantiles, and then finally I state the question.

#### Standard quantile function

Wikipedia states that the quantile function $F^{-1}:(0,1)\to\mathbb R$ defined by
$$ F^{-1}(a) = \inf \{ x \in \mathbb{R} : F(x) \geq a \}$$
is the **unique** function that fulfils
$$ a \leq F(x)  \quad\text{if and only if}\quad  F^{-1}(a) \leq x$$
and I can see the naturalness in that condition. Since we are not guaranteed an inverse of $F$ we settle with the next best thing: an almost-inverse that preserves partial order.

This is the only definition of a *quantile function* I've seen, and it seems natural.

#### "A quantile"

The second variant I have seen is from Allan Gut (2013) *Probability, a Graduate Course*. Similar definitions can be found in other works. Definition 7.1, p140 says (after replacing some symbols)

> The $b$-quantile $\lambda_b(X)$ of a random variable $X$ is a real number that satisfies
> $$P(X\geq \lambda_b(X))\geq b$$
>
> Remark: The median is thus a 1/2-quantile

I understand the definition as meaning "all" real numbers satisfying the inequality. This is useful for colloquialisms as "this falls in the 1/2-quantile" if a value is below the median, as the definition from above. The definition is awkward since it looks at right-tail probabilites, rather than left-tail ones, but that is a minor thing. In Exercise 11.2, p249, where $X$ is a standard normal, he makes this explicit by mentioning in passing that $F(\lambda_b)=1-b$.

#### "Quantile sets"

In Artzner, P., Delbaen, F., Eber, J.-M. & Heath, D. "Coherent Measures of Risk". *Mathematical Finance* 9, 203–228 (1999), yet another variant is proposed.

In this article, they first stipulate that $\Omega$ is finite. I guess this is to make sure that limits always exists and so on.... But anyway. Definition 3.2, after replacing some symbols, states that

> Given $c \in (0,1)$, the number $q$ is a $c$-quantile of the random variable $X$ under distribution $P$ is any of the following three conditions are satisfied
>
> i. $P(X\leq q)\geq c$ and  $c \geq P(X< q)$
>
> ii. $P(X\leq q)\geq c$ and  $ P(X\geq q)  \geq 1-c$
>
> iii. $F(q)\geq c$ and $c \geq F(q_-)$ where $F(q_-) = \lim_{x\to q,r<q}F(x)$
>
> Remark: The set of such $c$-quantiles is a closed interval. Since $\Omega$ is finite, there is
> a finite left (respectively, right) end point $q^{-}_{c}$ (respectively, $q^{+}_{c}$) that satisfies $q^{-}_{c} = \inf \{ x  : F(x) \geq a \}$ [equivalenty $\sup \{x:F(x)<c\}$] (resp. $q^{+}_{c} = \inf \{ x  : F(x) > c \}$. With the exception of at most countably many $c$, the equality $q^{-}_{c}=q^{+}_{c}$ holds. [...]

## My question

These three notions share a lot, but they handle edge cases quite differently. For continous, strictly monotonous $F$, the differences are not too interesting, but they work out differently where $F$ has jumps and plateaus. And it bugs me, since I am working with a discrete distribution, and then $F$ is jumps and plateaues *everywhere*.

Is there a unifying view that gathers all these three variants of quantiles, or that motivates their differences?

Is there a way to talk about left- and right-quantiles within the framework of the standard quantile function?

Is there any source you consider authorative on the definition of quantiles in various forms?

#### Close duplicates

[Is there one universally agreed-upon definition of a quantile? If not what definitions exist?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/481837/is-there-one-universally-agreed-upon-definition-of-a-quantile-if-not-what-defin) is a similar question is raised, but solely from a practical/software perspective. I am rather looking for a mathematical discussion.

[Are there two different possible meanings for a quantile group?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/430607/are-there-two-different-possible-meanings-for-a-quantile-group) is confused about various meanings of quantile groups, but I am interested in point quantiles.

[Definition of quantile](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/10728/definition-of-quantile) is only about sample quantiles.